# Redirect HTTP POST request to another sub-domain if some parameter is not empty

Tags: linux, nginx, http-post, cloudflare

I am integrating my web app with **Cloudflare** and Cloudflare responds with **524** to long running processes after 100 seconds. 
Cloudflare offers the solution to make a separate sub-domain for this process. Ok, I want to redirect my HTTP POST request to my newly created subdomain, **if a specific parameter's value is not empty**.

Running Linux with nginx as a web server. Following link only shows how to redirect from one sub-domain to another in Cloudflare but I want redirect on the basis of POST parameter's value.

[link] https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/105897/cloudflare-dns-how-to-301-redirect-all-traffic-from-sub-domain-to-main-domain-w

For Example, Considering **evidence** parameter, the following is the data of POST request. As show below, this request should not be redirected to new/another subdomain.

```
{
    "request_id"    : "",
    "callback_url" : "http://www.example.com/",
    "email"        : "",
    "document"         : {
        "evidence"           : "",
        "document_number" : ""
    }
}
```

But if **evidence** parameter is not empty as show below, then this request should be redirected to new/another subdomain.

```
{
    "request_id"    : "",
    "callback_url" : "http://www.example.com/",
    "email"        : "",
    "document"         : {
        "evidence"           : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAALCAYAAABCm8wlAAAABmJLR0QA=",
        "document_number" : ""
    }
}
```

Is there any **nginx configuration rule or Cloudflare Page rule** that can solve this problem? I'll thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with the default nginx installation. You'll need to install lua-nginx-module and use ngx.req.get_body_data. I think the documentation is clear on how to to what you asked.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxreqget_body_data

Comment: can you please share the dedicated configurations?

Answer (score 0):

A few points to remember:

- Use a temporary redirect, not a permanent redirect, because it's dependant upon the content posted, and you don't want to break any bookmarks for the page.
- Use a 307 not a 301. A 307 should redirect a POST, whereas a 301 should redirect to a GET in a modern browser.
- The user might be asked if they want to resubmit, so your site might end up black listed for appearing to phish.

Another option is to use a Cloudflare worker to handle the POST request. The worker could forward the POST request to the correct back end, without affecting the user's experience at all.